# Что у меня не так с SQL запросом?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Вообще не могу понять как связать подзапросы с JOIN

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GROUP"
LINE 35: GROUP BY
```

```
SELECT 
    authors.id, 
    CONCAT(authors.lastname, ' ', authors.firstname, ' ', authors.middlename) AS name,
    COUNT(ja) + COUNT(jaa) AS journal,
    COUNT(spa) + COUNT(nspa) AS publication
FROM "authors"
    INNER JOIN (SELECT table1.id
        INNER FROM "table1"
        INNER JOIN table2 aal 
            ON aal.author_id = authors.id
        WHERE table1.id = aal.publication_id 
            AND table1.is_hidden_en = false
            AND aal.itemtypes= 1) ja
    INNER JOIN (SELECT table3.id
        FROM "table3"
        INNER JOIN table2 aal 
            ON aal.author_id = authors.id
        WHERE table3.id = aal.publication_id 
            AND table3.is_hidden_en = false
            AND aal.itemtypes= 4) jaa
    INNER JOIN (SELECT table4.id
        FROM "table4"
        INNER JOIN table2 aal 
            ON aal.author_id = authors.id
        WHERE table4.id = aal.publication_id 
            AND table4.is_hidden_en = false
            AND aal.itemtypes= 2) spa
    INNER JOIN (SELECT table5.id
        FROM "table5"
        INNER JOIN table2 aal 
            ON aal.author_id = authors.id
        WHERE table5.id = aal.publication_id 
            AND table5.is_hidden_en = false
            AND aal.itemtypes= 3) nspa
GROUP BY 
    authors.id
ORDER BY 
    ja + jaa + spa + nspa
    DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Может ошибка потому, что ни для одного INNER JOIN не прописано `ON` ?

Comment: Если примерно представить запрос то получается `FROM "authors"
    INNER JOIN '123' as ja INNER JOIN '555' as jaa INNER JOIN '777' as spa ` ...... Скажите, это корректный синтаксис?

Comment: Вот эта кострукция тоже смущает `INNER FROM "table1"`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Проблема просто в том, что я не понимаю для чего добавить ON, потому что подзапрос айди авторов возьмет без любых ON, а сам подзапрос достает нужный мне список. Поэтому я теряюсь какой ON добавить

Comment: Если ваши "подзапросы" возвращают гарантированно 1 строку, то можно их вынести в select как отдельное поле. ON служит для сцепки таблиц, как бы вы говорите, что к таблице table прицепи(JOIN) таблицу table2 по условию(ON) что поле table.id равно table2.id(условно).

Comment: У вас сам запрос очень неправильный. ..... Я примерно понимаю суть, но, оптимально, если бы вы создали новый вопрос, описали структуру таблиц, данные и точное описание того, что хотите сделать... и какой output Ожидается

Comment: Хотя, возможно, тут вообще даже сама структура БД неправильная и много одинаковых табилц с одними и теми же полями

Comment: @SwaD Проблема добавления под запроса в селект в том, что добавив его туда я не смогу его фильтровать через ORDER BY

Comment: Ну через `order by` вы ничего не отфильтруете, это сортировка